# How to convert a string so to correctly pass that in an URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, url

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and I would like to convert a string so to correctly pass that in an URL. For example to convert from something like `some_text to%convert&èì` to some else...

**What are *Pros*, *Cons* and *Advices*?**

Comment: I can't really understand the question, could you clarify a little?

Answer (score 4):

I think  you should try with URI.escape

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html

Don't forget to `require 'open-uri'`

Comment: I think you mean `require 'uri'`; `open-uri` modifies `open` to also be able to accept URIs.